# store the index based array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Hi I have use the following code snippet to create the array .

```
var rows = [];            
rows["_id1"] = 1;
```

but in this case 1 did not insert into the array. Is there any other way to achieve this.

Screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It definitely did get turned into a property on the array, but that’s not a feature specific to arrays. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: As you can see, you didn't insert it into the array, instead you made a property.

Comment: what result do you expect?

Comment: I want to rows as like newly attached screen shot in  that i want id0 instead of 0 .is there any other way to achieve this

Comment: Arrays in JavaScript are *numeric only*, there are no associative arrays.  What you did was set a property of the array, you did not "insert" into it.

Answer (score 5):

Make it an object.

```
var rows = {};
rows["_id1"] = 1;
```

Or if you really want an array, you can have an array of objects

```
rows.push({"_id1": 1});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, in this case how to use the indexOf option from rows . i have tried with but it always return -1 as index

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you use an object, you won't be able to find the index. Are you trying to see if something is in rows? If so, you can just do `if (rows["_id1"])...`